# Changing node to manager in docker swarm - what command should I use

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want to add manager to my docker swarm environment.
I can run [update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_update/):
`docker node update --role manager my_node_name`
or [promote](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_promote/)
`docker node promote my_node_name`

Is there any difference between those two command?

Docker I'm on:

```
docker -v
Docker version 1.13.0, build 49bf474
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the node is a worker I think the result of the two commands are the same. The difference is IMO when you use this commands in scripts.

```
root@docker-1:~# docker node promote docker-1
Node 123123123123123 is already a manager.
root@docker-1:~# echo $?
0
root@docker-1:~# docker node update docker-1 --role manager
docker-1
root@docker-1:~#
```

which means the outputs (you can handle if you want) are different. Interesting that promote an already master is not an error.

Your question's title is not what you ask in the description by the way. Adding a manager node to the swarm is as simple as using

```
docker swarm join --token ...
```

With a manger token you can add a manager node to the swarm in one step, and you don't need to promote it. (so this is a third way for creating a manager node)